# button not working/function not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to post something(render on the screen) when I press a button. 
Pressing the button doesn't give any errors but also doesn't give the result I expect from it. I'm new to react.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default class Main extends Component {
    newBlog = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Post name = "James" about = "about java" post = "javs is great for complex software apps"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>           
                <button onClick = {this.newBlog}>Post-Blog</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Post extends Component {
    render() {
        const { name, about, post} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className = "main">
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <h2>{about}</h2>
                <hr/><br/>
                <p>{post}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer to your comment. 
if i understand your point

```
 import uuid from 'uuid/v4'; // get by npm install --save uuid || generate an unique id at each call
 class Main extends React.Component {
     constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            myBlog: [],
        }
    }

createNewBlog = () => {
    var myPost = { name: 'John', about:'Javascript', post:"i'm john, i'll take about javascript"}
    var currentMyBlog = this.state.myBlog;
    currentMyBlog.push(myPost);

    this.setState({myBlog: currentMyBlog});
};

render() {
    return(
        <div className=''> 
            {this.state.myBlog.map(post => (
                <div key={uuid()}>
                    <Post name={post.name} about={post.about} post={post.post}/>
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={ () => this.createNewBlog()}> Post blog</button>
        </div>

    )
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The Returned JSX on button click needs to be rendered somewhere. You are better off setting a visible state on button click as onClick handler on Button doesn't do anything with the returned value in your case. Check the below snippet

```js
class Main extends React.Component {
    state = {visible: false}
    newBlog = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Post name = "James" about = "about java" post = "javs is great for complex software apps"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
    toggleVisible = () => {
        this.setState(prev => ({visible: !prev.visible}))
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>  
               {this.state.visible? this.newBlog(): null}
                <button onClick = {this.toggleVisible}>Post-Blog</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Post extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name, about, post} = this.props;
        return(
            <div className = "main">
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <h2>{about}</h2>
                <hr/><br/>
                <p>{post}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use an arrow function with onClick event. 
try that in render of Main component

```
render() {
    return(
        <div>  
           {this.state.visible? this.newBlog(): null}
            <button onClick ={() => this.toggleVisible}>Post-Blog</button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: it does do it once but I want to create sort of new blog with button click below the last blog(sort of)